# jquery .css() not working on hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover

I am trying to implement a behavior on a div on hover event through jquery. Here is my code

```
var content = $('<div class="container col-xs-12 content"> ...some content... </div>');

content.hover(
     function () { 
         /* on enter handler */ 
         $(content).css({'border': '2px solid #add7f5'});
     },
     function () {             
         /* on leave handler */                   
         $(content).css({'boder': 'none'});
});
```

The first handler is working and the style is applied to the content. Although the second callback (on leave handler) is called, its style is not applied on the div and so the borders are not removed.
Use the Inspector (chrome and FF), I can see that the first style is still there although i have called .css({'border', 'none'}). Why is the first style applied and not the second? Thx in advance.

Comment: I don't get it. I have spend 2 days and nights trying to solve this problem. I have read tens of similar questions on stackoverflow, none of the solutions have worked for me. It is difficult for me to  create the conditions to reproduce the problem because this code is part of a larger ensemble. I cannot upload all the css files and js files including on this page. Also the specific element is dynamically created and appended on a dynamically created table...The inspector (chrome,ff) does not show me which parent override my rule. hence i come to S.O for more help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple typo - `boder`:

```
$(content).css({'boder': 'none'});
```

should be

```
$(content).css({'border': 'none'});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick answer. I have corrected the typo as suggested. But still the second style is not applied

Comment: If the handler is definitely running, there must be something else going on in the page structure that can't be seen by the example given - as per the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wt9dwbg3/) made by @JqueryKing, this should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = $('<div class="container col-xs-12 content"> ...some content... </div>').appendTo("body");
content.hover(
     function () { 
         /* on enter handler */ 
         $(content).css({'border': '2px solid #add7f5'});
     },
     function () {             
         /* on leave handler */                   
         $(content).css({'border': 'none'});
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/j18mL8re/)

### [DEMO(CSS Only)](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/42epto68/)

Comment: I have corrected this typo (boder --> border). Since this piece of code is part of a larger ensemble, could it be a problem due to 'css specificty' rules? If that is the case, I thought that applying a rule via jquery .css(...) is equivalent to an inline style ( style="..." ) directly on the html element and in this case has a higher weight on the cascading chaine. so it should work despite any corresponding inherited rule...